# React Redux - How to store form state so that it can be populated again when user returns to page

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a search form that loads results. Everything gets updated in the Redux state except for the values selected in the form fields.

Lets say the search below shows 3 results. User clicks on result #2 and does not like it. The click the back button but the form state is cleared. How can I avoid this and make sure the form state stays ?

I am storing the results in Redux and able to load that but not sure how to handle state. I dont want to use packages such as redux-form if possible because this is the only place I need to store form state.

[image]

The state does not update when I change the selections. This is probably a slight change in code for an expert but I am beginner and this is my first React-Redux app.

Also, when I navigate away from the page, the state that was last stored is not retained. This is probably because of the local state `formValues: {}` that I am initializing but without this, there are errors. I tried to delete local state and just use props but it is giving me errors on the select box at this line - `value={this.state.formValues['gender']}`

Here is the overall code of the component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { get } from 'axios'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { FadeIn } from 'animate-components'
import {
  getSearchResults,
  setSearchedOnce,
  setPageNum,
  setFormValues,
} from '../../actions/searchresults'
import SearchResult from './Result/searchResult'
import SearchNoResult from './Result/searchNoResult'

class SearchAdvanced extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { searchedOnce: false, users: [] }
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    this.props.setFormValues(this.props.formValues)
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    this.props.setSearchedOnce(true)
    const apiSearchURL = `/api/search/religion/${this.props.formValues.religion}/gender/${this.props.formValues.gender}`
    get(apiSearchURL, { maxContentLength: 400 })
    .then((searchResults) => {
      this.props.getSearchResults(searchResults)
    })
  }

  loadMoreClick() {
    this.props.setPageNum(this.props.pageNo + 1)
  }

  render() {
    const { users } = this.props
    let mapPageNo = this.props.pageNo
    let map_usersList = users.data && users.data.slice(0, mapPageNo * 2).map((userlist => (
      <SearchResult key={userlist.id} {...userlist} />
    )))
    let mapSearchedOnce = this.props.searchedOnce
    return (
      <div>
      <FadeIn duration="300ms">
        <div className="mid_rig_inner">
          <div className="mid_inner">
            <ul>
            { mapSearchedOnce
              ?  map_usersList
              :  <SearchNoResult/>
            }
            {
              mapSearchedOnce ?
              (mapPageNo * 2 >= 3)
              ?
              <div className="text-center my3 text-danger">
                No more profiles. Try to modify search criteria.
              </div> :
              <div className="text-center my3">
              <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary" onClick={this.loadMoreClick.bind(this)}>
                   Load More
                </button>
              </div>
              : ''
            }
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div className="rig_inner">
          <div className="my-4">
            <div className="recomm">
              <div className="recomm_top">
                <span>Search</span>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="search_advan_box">
              <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}>
                <select
                  name="religion"
                  className="mb-2"
                  value={this.props.formValues.religion}
                  onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
                >
                  <option value="" disabled="">
                    Select Religion
                  </option>
                  <option value="Any">Any Religion</option>
                  <option>Christian</option>
                  <option>Hindu</option>
                  <option>Muslim</option>
                  <option>Jain</option>
                  <option>Buddhist</option>
                  <option>Sikh</option>
                  <option>Parsi</option>
                  <option>Jewish</option>
                  <option>Spiritual</option>
                  <option>No Religion</option>
                  <option>Other</option>
                </select>

                <select
                  name="gender"
                  className="mb-2"
                  value={this.props.formValues.gender}
                  onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
                >
                  <option value="" disabled="">
                    Select Gender
                  </option>
                  <option>Male</option>
                  <option>Female</option>
                  <option>Other</option>
                </select>
                <input
                  type="submit"
                  className="my-4 btn btn-primary p2"
                  value={mapSearchedOnce ? "Refine Results":"Search Profiles"}
                />
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>

          </div>
        </div>
        </FadeIn>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  users: state.Result.users,
  searchedOnce: state.Result.searchedOnce,
  pageNo: state.Result.pageNo,
  formValues: state.Result.formValues
})
const mapDispatchToProps = {
    getSearchResults,
    setSearchedOnce,
    setPageNum,
    setFormValues
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(SearchAdvanced)
```

Comment: Presumably you are wondering why those values don't get updated?  Or do you want to know how to make them get updated?  What is your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The state does not update when I change the selections

This is because you are not dispatching a Redux action in your `handleChange` method, only in your `handleSubmit` method. Simply dispatching the appropriate action in `handleChange` will resolve this issue.

> when I navigate away from the page, the state that was last stored is not retained

This is because the values from before (before you navigate away) will only be kept in the Redux store, while the form fields are populated from the local state of the `SearchAdvanced` component.

To solve this one well, you should get rid of your local state entirely. Instead only use the Redux store. Keeping both intact is unnecessary and breaks the 'Single Source of Truth' that Redux is meant for. I recommend you do away with the local state and only update the Redux state and then pass values to the form inputs from the Redux store (`props` for the component).

Regarding your note that you tried this, but get errors: you need to change anything like:

```
<input value={ this.state.formValues.someValue }/>
```

to

```
<input value={ this.props.formValues.someValue }/>
```

where `formValues` comes from the Redux store.

**Update**

Problem now is the line

```
this.props.setFormValues(this.props.formValues)
```

in `handleChange`. You're using the old formValues to update, so the store never actually updates. I think you want something like:

```
handleChange(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const { name, value, type, checked } = event.target;
    this.props.setFormValues({
        ...this.props.formValues,
        [name]: type === 'checkbox' ? checked : value
    });
}
```

So that you are updating the store's `formValues` with the input from the user. The ternary operator is necessary for checkbox inputs since the `value` of a checked checkbox is `'on'` rather than `true`, but the `checked` attribute is `true` if checked.

**Extra**

It seems that you pass the dispatch method to the `SearchAdvanced` via props from the parent. You can (and should) do this more cleanly by using the second argument of `connect`, which is `mapDispatchToProps`. Here's an example:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = {
    getSearchResults,
    setSearchedOnce,
    setPageNum,
    setFormValues
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(SearchAdvanced);
```

Then you can just call any of these as methods that already have a dispatch bound to them. So

```
this.props.dispatch(setSearchedOnce(true))
```

becomes

```
this.props.setSearchedOnce(true)
```

and you can remove the passing of the dispatch from the parent component.

Docs on `connect`: https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options

Comment: Thanks for the details and I learned something new about mapDispathToprops. So I made all the changes which you suggested (updated code in question) and I tried this before I posted the question. I am getting empty payload. Earlier when using state, the payload was getting updated and redux state was also getting updated. Now, its just empty all the time. Is this correct -  `value={this.props.formValues.gender}` ? Or is there anything extra I need to do in handleChange(event) ?

Comment: I `console.log(this.props.formValues.gender)` in handle submit and its undefined. Thats why the payload is empty. Should'nt  `this.props.formValues.gender` fetch the selected value ?

Comment: You are a genius. I wish I knew all this but again this is my first react App. Thanks much for your help and using your skills to help others.

Comment: Hahah no problem, glad that helped! There are a lot of little things to keep track of when building in React, but they can be picked up with a bit of experience. The docs are great resource: https://reactjs.org/docs/getting-started.html