# How to externalize select options in a React App?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a React Redux App that has various select boxes. Right now I have it hard coded in the js files. 
I need these for the following pages: Edit profile, View Profile, Search selections.. 
I do not think it makes sense to have this long list in each pages.

How to externalize these options - I would like to store this in a single JS file and use the options only when needed.

Please note, my question is NOT how to create a select component. That I already did below. The question is how to pull the `<option>` list from an external source.

My code sample is:

```
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import Select from '../others/input/select'

const InputCasteChristian = ({ value, change }) => (
  <div className="edit_caste_div">
    <Select
      placeholder="Select option"
      value={value}
      valueChange={e => change('caste', e)}
      className="edit_caste mb-2"
    >
      <option value="" disabled selected>
        Select Caste
      </option>
      <option>Anglo-Indian</option>
      <option>Born Again</option>
      <option>Brethren</option>
      <option>CSI</option>

      <option>Unspecified</option>
    </Select>
  </div>
)

InputCasteChristian.propTypes = {
  value: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  change: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
}

export default InputCasteChristian
```

Update

```
import ReligionInput from './religion-input'
...
...
    return (
      <div>
        <Title
          value="Edit profile"
..
...
    <div className="profile_right">
       ....
    <ReligionInput value={religion} change={this.change} />
...
...
..

const mapStateToProps = store => ({
  ud: store.User.user_details,
  tags: store.User.tags,
  session: store.User.session,
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(EditProfile)
export { EditProfile as PureEditProfile }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to pass options as an array, and this component does not need to know how u create this list, you have just to pass it here.
And with use of map function , you can create the option list.

```
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import Select from '../others/input/select'

const InputCasteChristian = ({ value, change, options }) => (
    <div className="edit_caste_div">
        <Select
            placeholder="Select option"
            value={value}
            valueChange={e => change('caste', e)}
            className="edit_caste mb-2"
        >
            {options.map((a, index) => {
                return (
                    <option key={index}>{a}</option>
                );
            })}
        </Select>
    </div>
)

InputCasteChristian.propTypes = {
    value: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    change: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
}

export default InputCasteChristian
```

This is the caller component, see how I populate options:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import InputCasteChristian from './InputCasteChristian';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class InputCasteChristianCaller extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            value: '',
            options: props.options
        };
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <InputCasteChristian
                value={this.state.value}
                change={() => { }}
                options={this.state.options} />
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
    return {
        options: state.options
    };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        dispatch: dispatch
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(InputCasteChristianCaller);
```

I create an array object in constructor, and you could create this list like me or you could get it from an ajax call , ....

Comment: Makes sense but I dont see in your answer options being passed. Should that be stored as a json file ? And where is it being imported ? Also how about showing the options in view pages where the value in database will be 0,1,2 etc... How to translate that to values above ?

Comment: const InputCasteChristian = ({ value, change, options }) => (
See this line ? passing options array is just like passing change function or value object. 
can U share the code for calling this component ?

Comment: Thanks. I have added the relevant code for calling this component. I saw you are passing options but I am wondering where the list of options is coming from.. I mean the items in <option>

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: great. thanks much for the update. I will be calling this from many components. How to avoid adding these options array to each component? I think the list of options should be in one single place and not 3 callers if I call from 3 places. Do you agree ?

Comment: thats right. I want to introduce u to redux, use it , u could add this list to your redux, and use it any where you want.

Comment: If u want i can update the answer for the use of redux.

Comment: thanks. I am using redux for the state .. I have actions and reducers in place to store things like search results.. please look at my previous question where I show the screenshot.  I would like to know how to use it for select options as well
   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51885928/react-redux-how-to-store-form-state-so-that-it-can-be-populated-again-when-use/51887712?noredirect=1#comment90727189_51887712

Comment: The list for options is not different from search results.
You would update search results in store after an api call, but for options, you would create a store with default values. 
It is understandable for u ?

Comment: Yes, I get the concept. I did not know redux could store look up values permanently. So on componentDidMount should I just set the state of the options to the desired values - is that the correct approach ? Also I want to store value=1 that will map to Male, value=0 that will map to Female..

Comment: No just use mapStateToProps function on connect function.
Do u want me to share the code ?

Comment: if that is is not a problem, please. Thanks much for your time.

Comment: Thanks, I will give this a try. This is my first React App so will need some time. I will post the results after I make it work.

Comment: Your welcome, react is not really difficult, in addition with redux and redux-saga, and also server side rendering you can say you learn all aspects of react.